# Does the exclusive AND gate exist?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

[image: the attachment]

i have just received an assignment to identify what logic gate circuit of the given logic gate symbol indicates in the attached image. Parts a) and d) are easy, but are there gates like pictures b) and c)?

Is image b) an exclusive AND gate? Is this gate exist?

Comment: An exclusive AND makes no sense. AND logic requires all inputs to be on. Exclusive OR makes sense because it means that the output turns on if only one input is on.

Comment: All of these gates have only 1 input so they can only either be an inverter or a follower gate. Is this a homework assignment? If so, it's a confusing one.

Comment: Does your prof use any course specific meanings with the way these are drawn, like do you assume the gate has two inputs even if only one line is drawn?  I'm not sure what would make an OR doubly exclusive.  Try to put that in a sentence.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding anything similar with google.  Every variation of notted inputs and outputs, but not a double exclusivity line and no exclusive AND.  Has your professor tested how you deal with nonsense yet this semester?

Comment: @KH I've never seen these logic symbols (b and c) before and they are certainly not in common use or have a well known definition. As two-input gates they would also be superfluous as all of the common two-input logic functions can be performed with AND-OR-XOR-NAND-NOR-XNOR.

Comment: @Transistor. It's just terms. "Exclusive OR" makes no sense either. There are only 8 possibles gates with 2 identical inputs, and they have been named AND,OR,XOR,NAND,NOR,XNOR (+always set and always cleared).

Comment: @TEMLIB, **exclusive**
/ɪkˈskluːsɪv,ɛkˈskluːsɪv/
*adjective*
unable to exist or be true if something else exists or is true.
e.g. "mutually exclusive options" (Oxford English Dictionary). It makes sense to me.

Comment: They all have one input, and with one input the only logic gates that exist are buffer and inverter. So none of these symbols mean anything except the inverter in the upper right corner. They look cute though.

Comment: @TEMLIB An exclusive OR or XOR, which excludes the possibility of both inputs being true makes perfect sense when you consider that the regular OR is inclusive.  There are actually 16 natural 2 input logic functions.  You can find them on Wikipedia under truth table.  You can build any of the gates if you want to, just many of them aren't common, in formal logic or in electronics.  That said, none of those are these.

Comment: @KH. It's just that "Exclusive Or" is a bit an oxymoron, because of the ambiguity of the "or" word. As an alternative, there is the "Equal" or "EQV" gate, which is the same as "XNOR" for 2-input gates. It's just words, but it makes a difference for gates with more than 2 inputs.

Comment: @Temlib XOR for more than 2 inputs is true IFF one and only one input is true.   There are a lot of cases in formal logic and language that would rarely show up in electronics.  When a person gives their child options for sugary snacks, they may mean exclusively OR.  When they talk about options for the child's future prospects they more likely would mean to include the possibility of multipls

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it does exist, what do you expect its behaviour to be?

An OR gate is the disjunction of its inputs - its output is high iff at least one input is high.

An XOR gate's output is high iff *exclusively* one *or* other of its inputs is high.

An AND gate is the conjunction of its inputs - its output is high iff both inputs are high.

An 'XAND' gate's output is high... what, if each input (one *and* the other) is *exclusively* high? This cannot happen, its output will always be low.

If you like, the 'XAND' is your fixed logical low, and the similarly hypothetical/non-existent 'NXAND' is your high ('XNAND' would also be low). Nobody uses such terms.

Comment: A gate that outputs False regardless of inputs is a contradiction gate and a gate that outputs true regardless of its inputs is a tautology gate.